# Soap-->Clientdataset-->DBGrid in Delphi

Tags: delphi, xml, soap, web.xml

Пишу клиента Web сервиса. ТЗ такое: надо из полученного soap-ответа формировать xml пакет,назначить clientdataset-у и отображать его в DBGrid-е.
Ответ от сервера получаю и он отображается в Memo, а потом уже проблемы...

Есть 2 обработчика нажатия на кнопке 'GetServiceUsers', который возврашает список пользователей и Button_IPClick-возврашает IP клиента.
Пока есть только один обработчик нажатия на кнопке 'GetServiceUsers' всё работает правильно-в memo возвращается xml, а в DbGrid-е отображается clientdataset, полученный от SoapResponse.

Пока есть только обработчик нажатия на кнопке 'ServiceUsers'. Всё работает правильно - в memo возвращается xml, а в DbGrid-е отображается clientdataset, полученный от SoapResponse:

```
procedure TForm1.Button_ServiceUsersClick(Sender: TObject);
var
Fwbs: WayBillsSoap;
Frt: get_service_users;
FUser: get_service_usersResponse;
FXMLNode: IXMLNode;
FIndex: Integer;
begin
 Fwbs := GetWayBillsSoap(false, '', nil);
 Frt := get_service_users.Create;
 with Frt do
  begin
   user_name := 'satesto2';
   user_password := '123456';
  end;
try
FUser := Fwbs.get_service_users(Frt);
Memo.Text := FUser.get_service_usersResult.XMLNode.Xml;

with clientdataset1, FUser.get_service_usersResult do
begin
  if Active then Active := false;
  CreateDataSet;

  for FIndex := 0 to XMLNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Append;
   FieldByName('Id').AsString:=XMLNode.ChildNodes[FIndex].ChildValues['ID'];
    FieldByName('UserName').AsString := VarToStrDef(XMLNode.ChildNodes[FIndex].ChildValues['USER_NAME'], '');
    FieldByName('Un').AsString := VarToStrDef(XMLNode.ChildNodes[FIndex].ChildValues['UN_ID'], '');
    FieldByName('IP').AsString := VarToStrDef(XMLNode.ChildNodes[FIndex].ChildValues['IP'], '');
    FieldByName('Name').AsString := VarToStrDef(XMLNode.ChildNodes[FIndex].ChildValues['NAME'], '');
    Post;
  end;
end;

finally
  FreeAndNil(Frt);
  FreeAndNil(FUser);
  THTTPRIO(Fwbs).Free;
end;
 end;
```

Но как только добавляю другую процедуру - ServiceUsers, который возвращает IP-адрес моего компьютера, то выводится ошибка: Undeclared identifier XMLNode

```
procedure TForm1.Button_IPClick(Sender: TObject);
var
Fwbs: WayBillsSoap;
IP: what_is_my_ip;
IPResp:what_is_my_ipResponse;
//  FXMLNode: IXMLNode;
FIndex: Integer;
begin
 Fwbs := GetWayBillsSoap(false, '', nil);
 IP := what_is_my_ip.Create;
try
IPResp := Fwbs.what_Is_My_Ip(IP);
Memo.Text := IPResp.what_is_my_ipResult.XMLNode.Xml;

with clientdataset1, IPResp.what_is_my_ipResult do
begin
  if clientdataset1.Active then clientdataset1.Active := false;
  clientdataset1.CreateDataSet;

for FIndex := 0 to XMLNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    clientdataset2.Append;
    clientdataset2.FieldByName('what_is_my_ip').AsString  
                                       :=IPResp.what_is_my_ipResult.

    XMLNode.ChildNodes[FIndex].ChildValues['what_is_my_ip'];
    Post;
  end;
// end;

finally
 FreeAndNil(IP);
 FreeAndNil(IPResp);
 THTTPRIO(Fwbs).Free;
end;
end;
```

Uses выглядит так:

```
Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,   
System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,  
WayBillService, Vcl.StdCtrls,Soap.SOAPHTTPClient,Vcl.Buttons,
Vcl.ExtCtrls,Vcl.Grids,Vcl.DBGrids,  Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient, 
Xml.XMLIntf, Xml.xmldom;
```

Добавление и удаление в Uses Xml.XMLIntf, Xml.xmldom для второго ничего не меняет, а первая процедура работает и без них.

Кроме этого, этот код:

```
Memo.Text := IPResp.what_is_my_ipResult.XMLNode.Xml;
```

В первой процедуре **не вызывает** ошибку, а **во втором ругается**: Undeclared identifier XMLNode.

Если исправлю на:

```
Memo.Text := IPResp.what_is_my_ipResult
```

тогда работает, но почему так происходит?

[Download Zip(3.5mb)](http://f-bit.ru/692524)

Comment: Очевидно у разных методов разный ответ. Покажите описание `what_is_my_ipResponse`.

Comment: http://services.rs.ge/WayBillService/WayBillService.asmx?op=what_is_my_ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел в коде. Это не ошибка, это один из вариантов генерации классов по wsdl, так работает WSDLImporter. Свойство `get_service_usersResult` имеет тип `get_service_usersResult` (который `TXMLData`), а свойство `what_is_my_ipResult` строковое. При генерации биндингов есть настройки как учитывать примитивные типы: как примитивные типы или как классы, у вас string преобразовался в String. Все ок.

Comment: YuraIvanov,спасибо вам. Всё правильно работает.